# Can one customize what key strokes are sent by the VNC client?

Tags: vnc, realvnc

Is there a way to customize what key strokes are sent by the real VNC client to the server? I started at a new company and I used to be able to hit the windows key and then ALT-TAB to get to some windows OS window. At this company it seems like there client sends the widows key to the server so I am hoping there is some way to customize the client and tell it which keys to send and which ones not to send.  Hopefully I am making sense here. If I am not please ask me to clarify. The version of the client we are using is:

VNC Viewer Enterprise Edition E4.5.1 (r27892)

The client is running on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "customize key strokes," do you mean taking certain key presses and converting them into other keys for the server? I am not aware of how you could do this in this program, but I know the program I use (JollysFastVNC for Mac) has a "keyboard input" setting.

It lets you choose between none (view only, no input), normal input (basic keys are sent to the server, and system keys are used to control the client-side computer itself), invasive input (some of these system keys are sent to the server, but not all of them), and immersive input (as many keys are sent to the server as possible, and are ignored on the client side). If you can find something like that, it might be able to help you. Otherwise, it seems like you would be looking for a solution more specific to the software you're using, which I would not know about.

Comment: Nope, sorry I do not want to "customize the key strokes" or in other words change the binding of the keys. What I am trying to do is get vnc client to stop sending a key to the server and instead give it to the OS. Thanks for the comment though...

Comment: Keeping your VNC client in normal mode doesn't solve this problem?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "normal mode". I looked around in the options and did not see anything labeled normal. Could you explain what you mean by normal mode?

Comment: I mean a mode in which system keys are never sent to the server, they're used for the local machine only. That's what my VNC client calls it, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the viewer's options dialog, then select the Inputs tab, you can avoid systems keys like the Windows key and ALT-TAB being sent to the server by disabling "Pass special keys directly to VNC Server".

With this setting disabled all key presses will be applied at the viewer end, rather than the server end. The option is only available on the Windows version of the Viewer. The option is available in 4.5.x, 4.6.x and 5.0.x.